# How to filter on timestamps in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to retrieve documents newer than some timestamp using the AQL query below. The field `date` was stored as ISO strings like `2015-01-28T15:39:00.503Z`. Is there any other proper data type to store dates in ArangoDB?

`for m in messages
filter m.date > "2015-01-28T00:00:00"
return m`

EDIT:

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/arangodb/3Wt4c44mc0I), ArangoDB does not support any type of dates. They suggest ISO string comparisons as the way to go. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: So, I understand correctly that you have answered your own question in the edit? :) If yes, please make an answer out of it so it is easier for people to understand

Comment: @13abylon Almost that! :-) But, in fact, the question remains: is there something better than strings to store timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is only one additional format: the number of milliseconds since a fix point of time (1.1.1970?) see docu, search for "utc". But since this format is not very convient if you want to work with local times, I personally prefer to work with the strings (and typically Skiplists on them).

Answer (score 0):

like the answer of the @agustin-s, Try to set the date in number format milliseconds.
example Aql,

> for v in tweet
>           filter v.timestamp>=(DATE_TIMESTAMP(DATE_NOW()) - (6*10000))
>           return v._id